# Using high-resolution timer to implement square wave timer

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I was using a hrtimer to implement a square wave output with a GPIO.

The System is AR9331 + openwrt, and it does not support PWM output.

The snippet is the following,

Initialization and Start

```
hrtimer_init(&(s_WS2812_control.send_timer), CLOCK_MONOTONIC, HRTIMER_MODE_REL);
s_WS2812_control.send_timer.function = send_timer_handler;
hrtimer_start(&(s_WS2812_control.send_timer), ktime_set(0, 1000), HRTIMER_MODE_REL); //timeout now
```

My timeout handler is

```
send_period = ktime_set(0, 1000); //next timeout period is 1us
gpio_level = ~gpio_level;
gpio_set_value(out_pin, gpio_level);
hrtimer_forward(&send_timer,
    send_timer.base->get_time(),
    send_period);
```

My result was not logical since its timeout period(state-switching time) is not fixed. (observed in oscilloscope)

Sometimes it was something like 3.6us, sometimes it was 15us.

I think even if the execution time of handler was larger than 1us, the waveform should be a shift compared to 1us, but not like this, since timer interrupt is high-priority for system just like other hardware interrupt in my thought.

My Waveform is like this, the short/long period is like the above. I really can not understand why the GPIO output was like this.

[my waveform link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q16ov.jpg)

Please help if anyone know some clues about this, or any suggestion for timer tutorial/learning material is welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Logic on the timer seems ok, most likely the problem should be timer events. Is that timer the only thing running?

Comment: Thanks for your replay. This is also an important issue I want to check. Now I am only sure that when I opened this device/module, I did not launch any other program. But I think there is many other processes was running after booting. Could you please teach me how to monitor if there is event being triggered? Thanks.

Comment: You can monitor other processes the same way you would do on any linux system. Even though I am not completely fluent with openwrt that is normally not the targeted type of function to achieve with such system.  If providing square waves using GPIO's is the main thing you are trying to achieve, it might be useful to use different types of systems.